# KML File - Python - Log Query

Tags: python, kml, query

I want to know how many records are there in a KML file. Through what Python 2 code can I know this information?

Comment: Try fiona: https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#format-drivers-crs-bounds-and-schema

Comment: Thanks for the question.  Heads up that Stackoverflow/StackExchange discourages open-ended "how do I..." questions, and works best if you show what you've already tried (code or otherwise), and then ask how to fix it or do it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse KML in Python using PYKML: https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/